# how to generate a copy of this binary perl distribution

Tags: perl

I'm working with an application that downloads its own copy of Perl from a 3rd party website as a sort of bootstrap. I'd like to get a different copy from a more trusted source like CPAN, but I can't find any precompiled copies of Perl (only full source distributions) and I don't know how to build from source. Is there anywhere I can get a precompiled copy?

Another problem is that I don't know for sure that this download is just "a compiled copy of Perl". I'm *assuming* that, but I don't know what it's supposed to look like.

It comes in a .tar.gz which really only has two directories populated:

```
/bin (contains perl, cpan, perldoc, enc2xs, etc)
/lib/5.16.3 (contains subdirectories for various CPAN modules)
```

So to summarize: 1) Is this what Perl looks like when it is compiled? 2) Where can I get a pre-compiled version of Perl for my OS (RHEL 7), or if this isn't possible, how can I best generate a compiled version?

PS: For those who are curious, this is the copy of Perl that is downloaded by Miyagawa's Heroku Perl buildpack (https://github.com/miyagawa/heroku-buildpack-perl), which I am using for a project. He downloads copies of Perl stored on a website cache.bulknews.net, which might just be his own hosting, not sure.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the copy of Perl that's already present as part of your OS installation?

Comment: @duskwuff this is for a Heroku app, or technically for something like a Heroku app hosted by a company internally. I was advised not to rely on system perl since it can change and in theory break things. The idea behind these sorts of apps is that they're supposed to be totally self-contained, and that extends to pegging Perl and its libraries to specific versions, with the code owned by the app. One could argue that it's a bit paranoid, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I don't know how to build from source*

This is documented in [`INSTALL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/INSTALL) in the distribution.

It's quite simple on a unix system:

```sh
cd /tmp
wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.26.1.tar.bz2
tar xvjf perl-5.26.1.tar.bz2
cd perl-5.26.1
sh Configure -des -Dusethreads -Dprefix='/some/dir'
make
make test
make install
```

You might also want to pass `-Duserelocatableinc` to make the install relocatable.

You can also use [`perlbrew`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-perlbrew/bin/perlbrew) or [`plenv`](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv/releases) to assist you with installing `perl` and managing multiple installs of `perl`.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me something similar to the download I'm trying to replicate. Do you know, for the -Dprefix value, do I need to make sure it is equal to the directory where I will ultimately place perl, or can it just be any directory where I want the resulting files to be placed in the short term?

Comment: Final destination (though that can be changed if you pass `-Duserelocatableinc` to `Configure`). Additionally pass `DESTDIR=/staging/dir` to `make install` to place them somewhere else temporarily.

Comment: Sorry I am quite unfamiliar with this. In my case, I need to build a copy of Perl which will work when placed in several different directories. So are you saying that it would break if I don't use -Duserelocatableinc, but it should be fine if I do use it?

Comment: Correct. . . . .